# R Count elements of data frame and add a row

Tags: r

I am Reading data into two data frames, using this code:

```
IdaEmpA <- data.frame(table(unlist(DadosA$idade)))
IdaEmpB <- data.frame(table(unlist(DadosB$idade)))
```

Then I want to add a row with NAs quantity to those data frames. I tried like this:

```
IdaEmpA = rbind(IdaEmpA,c(7,sum(is.na(DadosA$idade))))
IdaEmpB = rbind(IdaEmpB,c(7,sum(is.na(DadosB$idade))))
```

The resulting data is:

```
> IdaEmpA
  RespA QuantA
1     1     11
2     2     13
3     3     15
4     4      3
5     5     18
6     6      1
> IdaEmpB
  RespB QuantB
1     1     18
2     2     14
3     3     21
4     4      2
5     6     13
```

But I am getting an warning and the value is not being added to the first column:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 7) :
nível de fator inválido, NA gerado

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 7) :
nível de fator inválido, NA gerado
```

Results after warnning:

```
> IdaEmpA
  RespA QuantA
1     1     11
2     2     13
3     3     15
4     4      3
5     5     18
6     6      1
7  <NA>      1
> IdaEmpB
  RespB QuantB
1     1     18
2     2     14
3     3     21
4     4      2
5     6     13
6  <NA>      3
```

How do I manage to have value 7 instead of NA???

Any clues might help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs when there is a factor column.  If the values in the new row for that column are not in the `levels` of the factor column, you will get this message.  For example, if I have both columns as "numeric" , there won't be an error.

```
 rbind(IdaEmpA,c(7,5))
 #  RespA QuantA
 #1     1     11
 #2     2     13
 #3     3     15
 #4     4      3
 #5     5     18
 #6     6      1
 #7     7      5
```

If one of the column is `factor`

```
  IdaEmpA$RespA <- factor(IdaEmpA$RespA)
  rbind(IdaEmpA,c(7,5))
  #  RespA QuantA
  #1     1     11
  #2     2     13
  #3     3     15
  #4     4      3
  #5     5     18
  #6     6      1
  #7  <NA>      5
  #Warning message:
  #In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 7) :
  # invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Because, the column in "IdaEmpA" appears to belong to "numeric" class, we can convert it to numeric before doing the `rbind`

```
  IdaEmpA$RespA <- with(IdaEmpA, as.numeric(levels(RespA))[RespA])
```

If there are multiple columns that needs to be reconverted to `numeric`

```
  indx <- sapply(IdaEmpA, is.factor)
  IdaEmpA[indx] <- lapply(IdaEmpA[indx], function(x)
                      with(x, as.numeric(levels(x))[x]))
```

This could be all avoided while reading the dataset using `read.table/read.csv`.  You can use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` so that the columns that are "character" class will not get converted to "factor"

Once you have corrected the `rbind` step, it would be easier to do `merge`.

#### data

```
IdaEmpA <- structure(list(RespA = 1:6, QuantA = c(11L, 13L, 15L, 3L, 18L, 
1L)), .Names = c("RespA", "QuantA"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```